# How to get the version of the current installed app using Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

I already found [AppAvailability plugin](https://github.com/ohh2ahh/AppAvailability) which basically checks if a user installed a certain app on his device.

Is there a possibility to the current version of the app, developer name (important) and everything it possibly can? Is this even possible in general?

Answer (score 3):

Using [`AppAvailability` plugin](https://github.com/ohh2ahh/AppAvailability) it is not possible to get the current version of the app.

You would have to use [Cordova AppVersion plugin](https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version) instead.

After install (e.g. `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-app-version`), you can this JS code:

```
cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber().then(function (version) {
    $('.version').text(version);
});
```

Here is the list of methods which you can use to retrieve other details about your application:

- `getAppName`

  > Returns the name of the app. E.g. "My Awesome App"
- `getPackageName`

  > Returns the package name of the app - the reversed domain name app identifier like `com.example.myawesomeapp`.
- `getVersionCode`

  > Returns the build identifier of the app
- `getVersionNumber`

  > Returns the version number of the app

---

Related posts:

- [How to get the application version and build in an iOS PhoneGap Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11550705/55075)
- [User versionName value of AndroidManifest.xml in code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3637665/55075)

Answer (score 0):

> Command Line

Also, the version can be found via the command line

```
$ cordova info
```

Scroll down until you see **Project Setting Files:**

```
 config.xml:
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <widget id="com.your.app" version="1.1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```